# Offsetting travel cost by selling luggage space?

Tags: budget, luggage, airlines, tips-and-tricks

If someone is flying internationally with just a back pack as a hand/carry on luggage and has an unused quota of about at least 50 lbs of luggage allowed, can the traveler *sell* this luggage quota of his ? The airlines don't give a hoot if you don't travel with luggage, they are not bringing down the cost of the ticket. 
Where can such a luggage space be advertized and how common is it for people to sell their luggage space ? 
If this luggage quota can't be sold, what can be done to offset the travel cost given that the passenger is travelling with just one bag less than 13 lbs and is allowed another 50 lbs.

Comment: The airline might advertise with a given allowance but the total capacity is obviously based on some estimate of how people are going to use it. So the airline certainly does reward you (and everybody else) for traveling without a bag, namely by allowing you to get a bigger bag, perhaps on another flight. If you are not flying budget, it's probably because you appreciate this flexibility (and a dozen other services that are part of the package). Otherwise, the solution already exists: Fly with an airline that charges extra for luggage, food, etc.

Comment: The big issue is going to be that you are responsible for that luggage. I can think of several organizations that want other people to take stuff on planes with them, but you don't want to be carrying anything for them.

Comment: I believe the technical term for what you're referring to is "drug mule". I hear it pays well... :)

Comment: Don't close this question. The very fact that it led to the revelation that a site like **[mmmule.com](http://mmmule.com/)** even exists makes it a good question.

Answer (score 17):

When people still checked in with an attendent, there was basically [one important question that you were always asked](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/20332):

> "Has your baggage been under your control at all times?"

The airport security announcement still tends to say:

> "Do not accept packages from strangers."

The idea of selling your luggage allotment is tantamount to accepting packages from strangers.  I doubt anyone to whom you sell would want you to examine it, and I for one wouldn't want to be the guy that smuggled the bomb onto the plane.

I'd say "Your mileage may vary," except if you did bring the bomb on board, your mileage would be significantly less than you'd like, in every instance.

There are courier companies that will sometimes pay you to be a courier, but in that case, you are taking a package that you can examine into your own luggage.  [There are instructions on the internet](http://www.wikihow.com/Fly-free-as-a-Courier), but personally I've never found the "free flights as a courier" thing to be anything but an urban legend.

Additionally, there are [other guys](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fat_Tony) who are little less legitimate, and they even will afford you [free accomodation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prisons_in_Turkey) for your troubles in certain instances.  Only problem is that entails a commitment of 5 - 10 years. :)

**tl;dr>** There is no freakin' way an airline will let you do this.  The security implications alone make it <strike>beyond stupid</strike> impractical.  And you'll note, I didn't even get into the airline's revenue stream.

Comment: On a serious note (as much as I love the sarcasm of the post :), there's actually a site that connects people who need (legal) things from another country with people willing to deliver it. Payment comes in various forms - money, accommodation, a tour of the city from a local etc. See http://mmmule.com/

Comment: And if you answer "no" when asked, they'll go through your bag with a fine-toothed comb, but they'll let it through if they find nothing.  Of course, if they *do* find a bomb or several kilos of heroin, you'll have a bit of explaining to do...